# Is there any diffrence between {} or default in initializing constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, initialization, default

Is there any difference (no matter how tiny is) between those three methods of defaulting the constructor of a class:

**Directly in the header using `{}`:**

```
//foo.h
class foo{
public:
    foo(){}
}
```

**Directly in the header using `default` keyword:**

```
//foo.h
class foo{
public:
   foo()=default;
}
```

**In the cpp using `{}`**

```
//foo.h
class foo{
public:
   foo();
}

//foo.cpp
#include "foo.h"
foo::foo(){}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there is a difference.

Option 1 and 3 are *user-provided*. A user-provided constructor is non-trivial, making the class itself non-trivial. This has a few effects on how the class can be handled. It is no longer trivially copyable, so cannot be copied using `memcpy` and the like. It is also not an aggregate, so cannot be initialized using aggregate-initialization

A fourth option is the following:

```
//foo.h
class foo{
public:
   foo();
}

//foo.cpp
#include "foo.h"
foo::foo()=default;
```

Although this may seem analogous to your second example, this is actually user-provided as well.

Functionally, the defaulted constructor does the same thing as your `foo(){}`, as specified in `[class.ctor]/6`.

Comment: Thanks...May I extend my question a bit and ask why (or when) should I make it trivial or non-trivial ?

Comment: Choosing to make your class trivial or non-aggregate probably doesn't buy you much unless you really don't want users treating it as such.